# Netlify form fetching a GET instead of POST request on submit

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify, jamstack, netlify-form

I have a basic Netlify form ([based on this guide](https://github.com/sw-yx/gatsby-netlify-form-example-v2/blob/master/src/pages/contact.js)) with `name`, `email` and `message` fields. With the following submit function:

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = {};
    const scopedForm = [...formState];

    let isValidForm = validateForm(scopedForm);
    setFormState([...scopedForm]);

    if (!isValidForm) return false;

    formInputs.forEach(input => data[input.name] = input.value);

    fetch(`/`, {
      method: `POST`,
      headers: {
        'Accept': `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`,
        'Content-Type': `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
      },
      body: encode({
        'form-name': `Contact Form`,
        ...data,
      }),
    })
      .then(() => console.log(`OK`))
      .catch(error => alert(error));
  };

  const encode = data => {
    return Object.keys(data)
      .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + `=` + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
      .join(`&`);
  };
```

Pretty simple, besides the validations, I create a `data` object and I fill it with a pair of  `data[input.name] = input.value`. Everything works as expected locally, as well as in `develop` and `build` mode. I can see a `POST` request, however, in production, it turns into a `GET`:

[image: Fetch request in production]

I've tried changing the built-in `fetch` to `axios` but the result is the same. I don't know if I need to add some custom configuration in my server or how to bypass this.

My resulting HTML structure is:

```
<form name="Contact Form" method="POST" action="/" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" data-netlify-recaptcha="true">
   <div><label for="form-name"><input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="Contact Form"></label></div>
   <div><label for="bot-field"><input type="hidden" name="bot-field" value=""></label></div>
   <div><label for="name">Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="Chancellor Lawson"></label></div>
   <div><label for="email">Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="fivyhohy@mailinator.com"></label></div>
   <div><label for="message">Message:<textarea name="message">Ea quisquam ea vel e</textarea></label></div>
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I have read a lot of similar issues, articles, and guides but none helped.

Comment: Could`validForm` be returning `False` before fetching?

Comment: No, because the `console` is prompting the `OK` message. I've tried removing the condition and the result is the same.

Comment: It's unlikely to be related to your actual problem, but telling the server that you'll only accept a **responses** that is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Check the *Type* column on the Network tab in Chrome. Make sure that the request you are looking at is one triggered by xhr. If it isn't, the code you provided isn't what is generating the HTTP request.

Comment: That did the trick @Quentin. Once I removed the `Accept` header it worked. If you add an answer I'll accept to close the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the issue, I will answer my own question, giving all the merits to [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin). As he pointed out, the solution was removing the `Accept` header since it only was accepting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` requests. So the header should look like:

```
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
  },
```

From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept):

> The Accept request `HTTP` header advertises which content types,
> expressed as MIME types, the client is able to understand. Using
> content negotiation, the server then selects one of the proposals,
> uses it and informs the client of its choice with the `Content-Type`
> response header. Browsers set adequate values for this header
> depending on the context where the request is done: when fetching a
> CSS stylesheet a different value is set for the request than when
> fetching an image, video, or script.